# How does ProGuard obfuscate class variables and logic?

Tags: java, proguard, obfuscation

I've tried to obfuscate a class file from a Java app and also a standalone Java class file containing `static void main(java.lang.String[])`. Anything I try on either file has resulted in the class and package getting turned to 'a', but meaningful code is left unobfuscated. Both class files I put into JARs before trying ProGuard.

So focusing on the standalone class (MyClass.class with `main(java.lang.String[])`)...

I went back to the default pro file in proguard/examples/standalone and used the library.pro, adding only these entries

```
-injars MyClass.jar

-outjars MyClass_Obf.jar

-dontshrink

-dontoptimize

-libraryjars c:\proguard\rt.jar

-printmapping out.map
```

Commented out all -keeps. This results in:

```
Number of obfuscated classes: 1

Number of obfuscated fields: 0

Number of obfuscated methods: 1
```

So then out.map lists only:

```
MyClass -> a;

  23:23:void <init>() -> <init>

  28:159:void main(java.lang.String[])-> a
```

and with a decompiler, that's what I see, just the class and main method both renamed to `a` and all the code intact and unobfuscated. Is there something I'm missing? I've googled all over the place, watched a guy on YouTube obfuscate with default and his variables and logic obfuscated.

The version is proguard-7.1.0-beta5. Here is the sample class file I was exploring obfuscation. It's just some goofing around with hashing, xor'ing, etc.

```java
public class MyClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            MessageDigest md=MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
            
            String ms="mystring";
        //HASHING STUFF    
            byte[] pre_hash_bytes=ms.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            byte[] post_hash_bytes=md.digest(pre_hash_bytes);
            String ms_hash=Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(post_hash_bytes);
            
            System.out.println(ms_hash + " - " + ms_hash + " - " + ms_hash.length());
        
        //ENCODE STUFF    
            String encodedString=Base64.getEncoder().withoutPadding().encodeToString(ms.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            System.out.println("encodedString-" + encodedString + "- encoded length - " + encodedString.length());
            byte[] encodedBytes=encodedString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            
        //DECODE STUFF    
            byte[] decodedBytes=Base64.getDecoder().decode(encodedString);
            String decodedString=new String(decodedBytes);
            System.out.println("decodedString- " + decodedString);
            
        //XOR STUFF    
            byte[] xor_guy=new byte[decodedBytes.length];
            for (int i=0;i< decodedBytes.length;i++) {
                xor_guy[i]=(byte)(decodedBytes[i] ^ encodedBytes[i]);
            }
            
            String xor_guy_string=new String(xor_guy);
            System.out.println("xor_guy_string (UGLY) - " + xor_guy_string);

    } catch (Exception exception) {
      exception.printStackTrace();
    } 
  }
}
```

and the .pro file

```
#
# This ProGuard configuration file illustrates how to process a program
# library, such that it remains usable as a library.
# Usage:
#     java -jar proguard.jar @library.pro
#

-verbose

-injars  MyClass.jar
-outjars MyClass_Obf.jar
-dontshrink
-dontoptimize
-libraryjars C:\proguard-7.1.0-beta5\lib\rt.jar

-printmapping out.map
-keepparameternames
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes Signature,Exceptions,
                InnerClasses,PermittedSubclasses,EnclosingMethod,
                Deprecated,SourceFile,LineNumberTable
```

**UPDATE**
this is the decompiled obfuscation of the above class. Basically, nothing, the decompiler accurately maps and plugs in it's own generic variable names. Thank you.

```
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.util.Base64;

public class a {
  public static void a(String[] paramArrayOfString) {
    try {
      MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");

      String str1 = "mystring";
      byte[] arrayOfByte1 = str1.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
      byte[] arrayOfByte2 = messageDigest.digest(arrayOfByte1);
      String str2 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(arrayOfByte2);

      System.out.println(str2 + " - " + str2 + " - " + str2.length());

      String str3 = Base64.getEncoder().withoutPadding().encodeToString(str1.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
      System.out.println("encodedString-" + str3 + "- encoded length - " + str3.length());
      byte[] arrayOfByte3 = str3.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

      byte[] arrayOfByte4 = Base64.getDecoder().decode(str3);
      String str4 = new String(arrayOfByte4);
      System.out.println("decodedString- " + str4);

      byte[] arrayOfByte5 = new byte[arrayOfByte4.length];
      for (byte b1 = 0; b1 < arrayOfByte4.length; b1++)
        arrayOfByte5[b1] = (byte)(arrayOfByte4[b1] ^ arrayOfByte3[b1]); 

      String str5 = new String(arrayOfByte5);
      System.out.println("xor_guy_string (UGLY) - " + str5);
    } catch (Exception exception) {
      exception.printStackTrace();
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: can you provide a minimum reproducible sample and proguard version used so thatwe can easily reproduce what you're facing?

Comment: You may want to read [ask]

Comment: What code is left unobfuscated? What are you expecting to happen to it?

Comment: @CausingUnderflowsEverywhere please see the "ADDITIONAL INFO" in the original post.

Comment: @tgdavies  I posted a portion of the class file under ADDITIONAL INFO, It's just some goofing around with hashing, xor, etc. I was thinking a good candidate to see how proguard would replace variable names with a, b, c, maybe scramble some of the sequence around. The guy on youtube I watched had what appeared like three different variables replaced with an 'a'. And stuff was moved around. But all I get is the class and method name being changed and when I add the -keep for public stuff, nothing is obfuscated. I'd like the opposite, keep the class and method name but scramble up the code stuff

Comment: @Robert thank you for the info. It's been a while, it was the end of the day and I was cranky.

Comment: okay thanks for the additional information Tom, lastly could you copy paste the obfuscated code into the question from your decompiler?

Comment: @CausingUnderflowsEverywhere Hi, added the Proguard obfuscated output (via decompiler) at the end of the original post. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to post my solution. I hadn't realized obfuscated fields are class level variables...local variables (inside the main method) are not fields. So that;s why the 0. Also obfuscation is most effective for jar/war apps with lots of classes as it makes mapping objects to classes harder when trying to weave through decompiled apps. thank you so much.